# WPF New line not working when saving text in RTF from a TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf

I use a TextBlock in WPF to display formated text. The display works fine but when I try to save the content to a file in RTF format the new line characters are not used. I get a "one line text".

I use lines of code like this:

```
displayBuffer.Inlines.Add(new Run("Blabla \n") 
    { TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline, Foreground = Brushes.Blue });
```

and save with:

```
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(dlg.FileName, FileMode.Create);
        TextRange range = new TextRange(displayBuffer.ContentStart, displayBuffer.ContentEnd);
        range.Save(fileStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
```

I have tried \n \r\n and Environment.NewLine for the end of line without success.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

EDIT:
Quite interesting idea to post process string to get right result (Stefano reference). I have looked at RTF format here http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/rtfspec_7.html#rtfspec_18 and \par is probably what I want but \line would be ok.

What is strange is that the RTF file generated by the Range.Save does not contain \line or \par at all ?
So may be I can replace \n by special char sequence as described in your reference and replace this character in the RTF file by \par.

However I would prefer to do this before saving the file. Is there a way to do an equivalent of range.Save(fileStream, DataFormats.Rtf) to save string in memory? Otherwise I will need to write a temp file process it and rewrite final one but all this looks ugly for something supposed to be simple?

Comment: I suggesto also to read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616132/how-to-append-line-into-rtf-using-richtextbox-control

Answer (score 2):

The following code implements a method that takes a RichTextBox as an argument, and returns a string representing the plain text contents of the RichTextBox.
The method creates a new TextRange from the contents of the RichTextBox, using the ContentStart and ContentEnd to indicate the range of the contents to extract. ContentStart and ContentEnd properties each return a TextPointer, and are accessible on the underlying FlowDocument that represents the contents of the RichTextBox. TextRange provides a Text property, which returns the plain text portions of the TextRange as a string.

Try this:

```
string StringFromRichTextBox(RichTextBox rtb)
{
    TextRange textRange = new TextRange(
        // TextPointer to the start of content in the RichTextBox.
        rtb.Document.ContentStart, 
        // TextPointer to the end of content in the RichTextBox.
        rtb.Document.ContentEnd
    );

    // The Text property on a TextRange object returns a string 
    // representing the plain text content of the TextRange. 
    return textRange.Text;
}
```

To save in rtf format correctly try this:

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Create))
{
    textrange.Save(file, System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf);
}
```

Comment: This works but it removes the "formatting". I have tried to replace the DataFormats.Rtf with DataFormats.Text and the output correctly contains the \n. It is just the RTF format that does not seems to work

Comment: I Edit my solution, try that, unfortunately now I cannot check it by myself on my visual studio :)

Comment: What you suggest is what I have described! I open the file with  Word 2013 and content has all the text and formatting but unfortunately the newline seems to be missing for some reason.

Comment: I believe it has more to do with the fact the rtf file charset is typically '\ansi' and the unicode codepage '\ansicpg1252' used by the getter. Newlines in the input text are encoded as rtf paragraph breaks '\par' per the rtf spec and re-emitted as a newline by the unicode rtf codepage.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the Unicode Line-Separator (U+2028) does work:

```
\u2028
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help. I have tried \u2028 as well as \u000D\u000A none works

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use a RichTextBox instead of a TextBlock (if you want to save the text in a rft file). Moreover insert a new [LineBreak](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.linebreak(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a simple "\n".

Comment: This is probably the best solution, but it is a lot of rewrite for a small problem of line feed. At least I can save in text without formatting using the DataFormats.Text. I have also tried the DataFormats.Html format. It compile correctly but at run time I am getting an exception error (something like HTML format not supported???)

Comment: Unluckly (at least in .NET 4.0) the method TextRange.Save supports just Text, Xaml, Rtf and XamlPackage DataFormats.

Comment: I have tried to use the following code  without success   LineBreak lb = new LineBreak();
displayBuffer.Inlines.Add(lb);

Comment: You must use LineBreak and RichTextBox otherwise it will not work