# How can I list the file names within a directory inside of a textbox?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make the text of a richtextbox be all the file names inside of a directory separated by lines and I have no idea how to do such a thing. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please write your question in brief ?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to read filenames? or to set the text of richtextbox?

Comment: It's not a one-step process.  Break it down into steps and then deal with each step individually.  For instance, displaying text in a `RichTextBox` is the same regardless of where that text comes from, so doing that has no specific connection to file names.  Divide and conquer.  EVERY time.

Comment: Alright, well I guess I'll put it this way, I'm trying to get the file names of all the files in a specified directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you get list of file names under a specific directory

```
String.Join(",",Directory.GetFiles("YourFolderName")
                         .Select(Function(d) Path.GetFileName(d)))
```

This will generate comma separated list of filenames. Replace comma with whichever delimiter you want.

Comment: How would I put this into a textbox?

Comment: Alright I'm able to put it into a richtextbox now but how would I separate each file name per line?

Comment: @Shayna : check this answer.. you might have to replace comma with suggested character from this answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616132/how-to-append-line-into-rtf-using-richtextbox-control

Comment: Alright, thanks although I made up my own dumb solution, I replaced it with a bunch of spaces which a richtextbox auto formats into a new line.

Comment: instead bunch of spaces replace it with `vbNewLine` remove the **`" "`**

Comment: Providing an answer when clearly the OP hasn't tried anything is off topic and discouraged here. It doesn't help the OP when you do this and it gives the wrong impression. We help with specific issues and or problems, not a "we give the codes".