# Autoscaling RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox, autosize

I am trying to use read-only RichTextBoxes to show user-generated text. The height of the textbox and control should depend on the content and be limited to a certain maximum, anything past that point uses scroll bars.

AutoSize does not appear to work for RTB's

```cs
public void Rescale()
{
    Point pt = rtbComment.GetPositionFromCharIndex(rtbComment.Text.Length);
    int height = rtbComment.GetPositionFromCharIndex(rtbComment.Text.Length).Y + (int)rtbComment.SelectionFont.GetHeight();
    if (height > 250)
        height = 250;
    this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(616, height + 50);
    rtbComment.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(614, height);
}
```

This works absolutely fine for short comments or comments with little text and many linebreaks, but for long one-liners that are broken into ~4 lines, the point I get from GetPositionFromCharIndex is all wrong - the function puts it somewhere at 105px down on the y-Axis when it's actually closer to 60, making the textbox about twice as big as it's supposed to be.

The width does not appear to be the issue here, as the box starts with the width I am setting it to and reading the point out again produces the same result.

Comment: You can't know what the size of a block of text will be when rendered on a specific page until you actually try to render it. RTF can have different fonts, sizes, line wraps controlled by hyphens etc. What you call line breaks may actually be *paragraphs* that have different spacing from the lines generated by line wrapping

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos when does it try to render, though? And I am referring to actual linebreaks in the string (\n)

Comment: RTF (the format) has no `\n` and RichTextBox [converts newline characters to /par instead of /line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616132/how-to-append-line-into-rtf-using-richtextbox-control)

Comment: In any case you can't easily control a *form's* layout from a specific control. The typical way is to either use docking or a layout panel like [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-arranging-controls-on-windows-forms-using-a-tablelayoutpanel), specify auto-sizing and maximum sizes on the panel/container and set the control to Fill its cell

Comment: Check [AutoSize Behavior in the TableLayoutPanel Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/autosize-behavior-in-the-tablelayoutpanel-control). This article also points to the [Control.GetPreferredSize()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.getpreferredsize?view=netframework-4.8) method which can be used to ask the RTB what size it wants to use. If you don't want to use a TableLayoutPanel you can try using `GetPreferredSize` to check how large the RTB wants to be and restrict it if it's too big

Comment: You can use [TextRenderer.MeasureText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext) to determine the size of the text when rendered inside a container of a specific size. If the width is fixed, provide a container (a Rectangle) of specific width, then get the height of the measured text and Min/Max it to the maximum height you pre-defined.

Comment: The MeasureText function was helpful. Since I still have to deal with both manual linebreaks and automatic ones (from the RTB being too small), it doesn't quite help with the problem, but now I am manually splitting each text by actual linebreaks from the string, then checking those lines with the MeasureText method and adding the necessary lines to the length. Will update my main post later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I used the [TextRenderer.MeasureText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext?view=netframework-4.8) method.

Since this method ignores the fact that very long lines will receive one or more automated linebreaks in the RichTextBox, I've written a function that manually splits the text into lines of any length by linebreaks, then measures each of these lines to check how many lines it'll use in the RTB.

Here's the function, in case anyone needs it:

```cs
public int getLines(string comment)
{
    int height_ln = 0;

    string[] lines;

    //split into lines based on linebreaks
    if (comment.Contains("\n"))
    {
        lines = comment.Split('\n');
    }
    else
    {
        lines = new string[1];
        lines[0] = comment;
    }

    //check each line to see if it'll receive automatic linebreaks
    foreach(string line in lines)
    {
        int text_width = TextRenderer.MeasureText(line, rtbKommentar.Font).Width;
        double text_lines_raw = (double)text_width / 1400; //1400 is the width of my RichTextBox

        int text_lines = 0;

        if (line.Contains("\r")) //Please don't call me out on this, I'm already feeling dirty
            text_lines = (int)Math.Floor(text_lines_raw);
        else
            text_lines = (int)Math.Ceiling(text_lines_raw);
        if (text_lines == 0)
            text_lines++;

        height_ln += text_lines;
    }
    return height_ln; //this is the number of lines required, to adjust the height of the RichTextBox I need to multiply it by 15, which is the font's height.
}
```

Comment: TextRenderer doesn't ignore at all the line breaks (forced or determined by word wrapping). You need to specify the correct TextFormat flags, though. Use these: `var flags = TextFormatFlags.LeftAndRightPadding | TextFormatFlags.Top | TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl | TextFormatFlags.WordBreak;`. In `TextRenderer.MeasureText()`, use the overload that allows a `IDeviceContext` and `TextFormatFlags` arguments. `IDeviceContext` can be generated using `Control.CreateGraphics()` (dispose of the Graphics object after).

Comment: Without `TextFormatFlags.WordBreak;`, for example, it will measure the Text as it was layout in a single line. You also need to specify the Size of the Container. Use `new Size(Control.ClientSize.Width, MaxHeight)` for this argument. When measured this way, TextRenderer will return the correct size of the Text inside the specified container's bounds.

Answer (score 0):

The WinForm RichtextBox exposes the [ContentsResized Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.contentsresized?view=netframework-4.8) that when coupled with the [MinimumSize Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.minimumsize?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Control_MinimumSize) and the [MaximumSize Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.maximumsize?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Control_MaximumSize) allows for a auto-sized control.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        rtbComment.MinimumSize = new Size(250, 200);
        rtbComment.MaximumSize = new Size(250, 400);
        rtbComment.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxScrollBars.Vertical;
        rtbComment.ContentsResized += rtbComment_ContentResized;

    }

    private void rtbComment_ContentResized(object sender, ContentsResizedEventArgs e)
    {
        rtbComment.Size = e.NewRectangle.Size;
    }
}
```